# Visual Studio for Linux crashes with a “ibdbus-1.so.3: no version information available” error

Tags: linux, visual-studio

I have downloaded and installed Visual Studio for Linux.  I try to start it with either `code` or `code --version` and get the error message in the question

```
/usr/share/code/bin/../code: /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by /usr/share/code/bin/../code)
```

Any ideas on how to correct this?

Comment: Linux what OS and how did you install is exactly?

Comment: I just started getting this on my OpenSUSE 42.3 Leap box too.  Looking into it as well.

Comment: This might help:
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/16364#issuecomment-492199424 I'm having the same issue on CentOS 7.4